# How much is VLIW power- and area-efficient then superscalar anyway?

Tags: microprocessor

Most of texts say VLIW, which is lack of hardware to detect hazards and schedule the instructions. But I haven't see any evaluation about how much VLIW can save area(h/w complexity) and power compared to matching superscalar.

When VLIW came out, the advancement of technology node size was slowing down, but not anymore. I want to know it's still valid to say VLIW can be considered to be efficient enough in power/area compared to equivalent superscalar.