# How much is VLIW power- and area-efficient then superscalar anyway?

Tags: microprocessor

Most of texts say VLIW, which is lack of hardware to detect hazards and schedule the instructions. But I haven't see any evaluation about how much VLIW can save area(h/w complexity) and power compared to performance-matching superscalar.

When VLIW came out, the advancement of technology node size was slowing down, but not anymore. I want to know it's still valid to say VLIW can be considered to be efficient enough in power/area compared to equivalent superscalar when enough ILP is given.

Comment: Opinions are not welcome as answers. As a specific question, get a decent answer. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Andyaka - I don't think this is a matter of opinion.  These designs have been tried and tested, and the benefits quantified -- and the industry as a whole has moved on, with new implementations of this kind of design extremely rare today.  I think we can answer this with reasonable certainty.

Comment: Why do you think that "node size was slowing down, but not anymore"? I would submit that the opposite is true - node size is at creeping stop, likely forever. Why would VLIW have any new life, if for every two-transistor gate you need 5 transistors to maintain local voltage to make it function?

Comment: I'm sure I answered *exactly* this question yesterday.... but it seems to have been deleted by the asker: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/387612/how-much-is-vliw-power-and-area-efficient-then-superscalar-anyway

Comment: @AliChen - I *think* what's meant by that is that in the 90s, when VLIW architectures were popular, and computational photolithography wasn't really much of a thing, it was expected that decreasing feature sizes much beyond where they were at the time was unlikely, and that Moore's Law would hit a hard barrier in the immediate future.  That turned out not to be true, but it was widely believed.  Today it's slowing down due to implementation difficulties that are making size reductions less beneficial than expected, but not due to the kind of physical hard limit that was expected back then.

Comment: @Jules I have to reuploaded the question since that was put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any reliable sources, but I do have experience of designing a [very simple processor](https://github.com/periata/cpus/blob/master/c61/c61%20complete%20v1%20whitebg.png) that took the approach of leaving avoiding pipeline hazards to the programmer, because that did provide a significant simplification for what was intended to be an as-simple-as-possible pipelined processor design.

That said, I don't believe that the savings scale: I may have saved a handful of flip flops and several gates that would have been necessary to avoid those hazards, and with only ~60 flip flops (excluding the register file) and ~100 gates in the entire design that was a significant percentage, but for a more complex processor the difference would, I think, have been trivial.

Instruction scheduling for an order-of-order processor is a little different, but even then the costs are small relative to the complexity of the processor, particularly as by the time you start looking at these kinds of optimisations you're likely to have added some comparatively big chunks of silicon for parallel multiply/divide operations, not to mention cacheing, which is likely to be more beneficial in most designs.

There's a reason almost nobody's designing VLIW or EPIC machines commercially any more -- it's an architecture that was only beneficial for a brief period of time[1] back in the 90s, and processor design has moved beyond the point where it makes any significant improvement.

[1] - at least for high performance general purpose systems.  For embedded processors and specialist systems like DSPs and GPUs it may still have some benefit (because they usually have designs that are towards the simpler end, only repeated many times in order to achieve parallelism, the tradeoffs for them are much closer to the tradeoffs for 90s era general purpose CPUs), but even there I'm not sure.